# NoClassDefFoundError when trying to reference external jar files

Tags: jsp, tomcat, classpath

I have some 3rd party jar files that I want to reference in my tomcat web application. I added this line to catalina.properties:

shared.loader=/home/ollie/dev/java/googleapi_samples/gdata/java/lib/*.jar

but I'm still getting this error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gdata/util/ServiceException
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:491)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:401)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

I verified that the com.google.gdata.util.ServiceException is in the gdata-core-1.0.jar file which is in the directory:

/home/ollie/dev/java/googleapi_samples/gdata/java/lib

I did bounce tomcat after I modified catalina.properties.

Update 1:
I tried copying the gdata-core-1.0.jar file into
/var/lib/tomcat6/webapp/examples/WEB-INF/lib
as a test but that didn't fix the problem either.

Update 2:
It actually does work when I copy the jar file directly into the WEB-INF/lib directory. There was a permissions issue that I had to resolve. But it's still not working when I use the shared.loader setting. I reconfirmed that the path is correct.

Comment: Might be permission issue. Check in which user Tomcat service is running. try chmod to grant the permission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about this one, but there are two potential causes:

1. There's a file permission issue in path as specified in `shared.loader`, probably the same as you had when fiddling with `/WEB-INF/lib`.
2. You aren't editing the `catalina.properties` file of the Tomcat instance you think you're using. For example, if you're running Tomcat from inside Eclipse, you need to ensure that you've configured Eclipse to take over Tomcat rather than using workspace metadata (where Eclispe actually runs based on a copy of Tomcat conf files). To do this, undeploy/remove all projects, doubleclick Tomcat entry and select *Use Tomcat installation* in *Server locations* section. Then the config files in Tomcat's own `/conf` folder will be used. Otherwise you need to edit it in `Servers` project of Eclipse workspace.

Comment: It was a permissions issue. I had only opened up the permissions on the jar files and the parent directory. I needed to open up the permissions to the tomcat user for every directory in the path.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try prefixing the path with `file://`?

```
shared.loader=file:///home/ollie/dev/java/googleapi_samples/gdata/java/lib/*.jar
```

Comment: According to the tomcat documentation, you only use the url format (file:///...) when pointing to an individual jar file, which I tried as well with the same result.